# export matlab data to python

Tags: python, import, export, workspace

I have a sentence ' i am unhappy' stored in variable 'a' in matlab. i want to extract data from matlab to python.
like if i write 'a' in python, it should display the whole sentence stored in MATLAB. and yes further i want to convert that sentence into speech using gtts.

i have tried,this:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
test = loadmat('value.mat')
```

but it gives error:

```
MatReadWarning: Duplicate variable name "None" in stream - replacing 
previous with new Consider mio5.varmats_from_mat to split file into 
single variable files matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
```

Comment: How did you save what in which version of a mat-file?

Comment: @SpghttCd i dont know much about this... i just tried this code :  
     filename = 'test.mat';
      save(filename)

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459372/export-matlab-data-to-python) and you should check what the `Warning` (it's not an error) suggests -- this code: https://github.com/pv/scipy-work/blob/master/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py

Answer (score 0):

I could test it like this and had no problems:

In matlab:

```
>> a = ' hello mat file'

a =

 hello mat file

>> filename = 'test.mat'

filename =

test.mat

>> save(filename)
```

and then in python:

```
import scipy.io as scio

data = scio.loadmat('test.mat')

data
Out:
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Nov 27 10:20:58 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'a': array([' hello mat file'], dtype='<U15'),
 'filename': array(['test.mat'], dtype='<U8')}

data['a']
Out: array([' hello mat file'], dtype='<U15')
```

So no error message here.

However, note that in Matlab `save` by default saves *all* content of the current workspace in the mat-file. Could it be possible, that you have created some other variables which perhaps are of an unsupported type?

You could check by simply explicitly saving only your test variable `a`:

```
save(filename, 'a')
```

Does this lead to an importable mat-file in python?